# Cannot use NVIDIA Quadro P620 GPU with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have installed all things needed to run my GPU with Tensorflow, such as NVIDIA driver, Microsoft VisualStudio 2017 C++ distribution, CUDNN in the correct folder. But still I am unable to use the GPU. I receive the following message.

[image: Cannot find GPU]

---

The following are my software and hardware specifications.

- My GPU version is NVIDIA Quadro P620,
- Tensorflow, and TF-GPU versions are 2.3.0,
- Keras and Keras-GPU 2.4.3
- CUDA version 11.2.2
- NVIDIA driver version: 27.21.14.6192

Where can I start my debugging to solve this problem? Any lead?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tensorflow tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu), you need to install `CUDA 10.1` for `Tensorflow 2.3` version.

If there is any incompatibility between versions of `Tensorflow`, `CUDA` and `cuDNN`, it won't detect `GPU`.

In your case i would recommend you to upgrade `tensorflow` version to `2.4 or 2.5`, which supports `CUDA 11.x`.

From `tensorflow 2.0` onward `keras` is integrated with `Tensorflow`, hence there is no need of separate `Keras or Keras-GPU` installation. You can use `tf.keras` module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using it in my ubuntu 20.04 with:

- nvidia driver version 495.29.05
- tensorflow 2.4.0.

Maybe your problems is tensorflow version.

Regards